# GraphQL Where: greater than / less than

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, strapi

I am trying to figure out how to query "less than"/"greater than" using GraphQL towards strapi backend (using React/Apollo). Basically I would like the amount of bonus to be "not smaller" than $min_bonus, and "not greater" then $max_bonus...

What would be a good solution to this?

**My Query:**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";


const BONUSES_QUERY = gql`

query bonuses($min_bonus, $max_bonus, $welcome_bonus: Boolean, $deposit_bonus: Boolean, $monthly_bonus: Boolean, $weekly_bonus: Boolean, $slots_bonus: Boolean, $nodeposit_bonus: Boolean ) {
    
  welcome_bonuses: bonuses(where: 
    { 
      welcome_bonus: $welcome_bonus
      
    })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

  deposit_bonuses: bonuses(where: { deposit_bonus: $deposit_bonus })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

  monthly_bonuses: bonuses(where: { monthly_bonus: $monthly_bonus })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

  weekly_bonuses: bonuses(where: { weekly_bonus: $weekly_bonus })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

  slots_bonuses: bonuses(where: { slots_bonus: $slots_bonus })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

  nodeposit_bonuses: bonuses(where: { nodeposit_bonus: $nodeposit_bonus })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

}
fragment BonusParts on Bonuses {
          name
          casino { 
            name
            aff_link
            logo { 
              url 
            }
          }
          slug
          title
          amount
          code
          min_deposit
          value
          wager
          cashable
          bonus_type {
            name
          }      
  }


`;

export default BONUSES_QUERY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want greater than and less than but your description indicates you want *greater than or equal to and less than or equal to* so my suggestion is for that. You can sub `_gt` for `_gte` and the like if you don't want to include the limit.

[Here is the relevent Strapi documentation.](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/graphql.html#query-api)

You can append `_gte` and `_lte` to fields in your `where` clauses like so.

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";


const BONUSES_QUERY = gql`

query bonuses($min_bonus, $max_bonus, $welcome_bonus: Boolean, $deposit_bonus: Boolean, $monthly_bonus: Boolean, $weekly_bonus: Boolean, $slots_bonus: Boolean, $nodeposit_bonus: Boolean ) {
    
  welcome_bonuses: bonuses(where: 
    { 
      deposit_bonus_gt: $min_bonus, 
      deposit_bonus_lt: $max_bonus,
      welcome_bonus: $welcome_bonus
      
    })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

  deposit_bonuses: bonuses(where: 
    { 
      deposit_bonus_gt: $min_bonus, 
      deposit_bonus_lt: $max_bonus,  
      deposit_bonus: $deposit_bonus 
    })
  {
    ...BonusParts
  }

  ...
```